# onCreateView items should load only once in android swipeable tab

Tags: android, grid, fragment

SFragment is in a android swipeable tab and Im loading my grid on fragment onCreateView, so whenever i visit the tab it takes sometime my items to laod. but i dnt want those item to load each n everytime i open that tab.

what i want is it should load only in 1st attempt, after that whenever i open that tab it shouldnt load.
how can i achieve that, thank you in advance.

```
public class SFragment extends ListFragment implements OnTaskCompleted {

    GridView grid;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_grid_main_s, container, false);

        new SidesMenuAsyncTask(getActivity(), this).execute();


        grid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_s);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson) {

        try {
            List<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> imageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> price = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < responseJson.length(); ++i) {
                JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i);

                if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1") && (object.getString("SubCategoryID")).equals("1") ) {
                    Log.i("ImageURL ", object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    imageUrls.add(object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    Log.i("Description ", object.getString("Description"));
                    descriptions.add(object.getString("Description"));
                    Log.i("Price ", object.getString("Price"));
                    price.add(object.getString("Price"));
                }

            }

            CustomGridS adapter = new CustomGridS(getActivity(), descriptions, imageUrls, price);
            grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use **image loader** for load image and save that image in **cache memory** so each time you don't have to load image, image loader takes image from cache memory...

Comment: [plz Find that here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764850/loading-images-in-gridview-using-universal-image-loader)

Comment: where should i post that piece of code? is it inside onCreateView?

Comment: [is this code efficient for understanding? Android-GridView-ImageLoader](https://github.com/xomaod/Android-GridView-ImageLoader/blob/master/GridView/src/com/example/gridview/MainActivity.java)

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the response from the server, store it in sqlite db and retreive it from the database whenever you want to load the content on your fragment.